# What is different between operation and REST resource method in WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I have a query to select all students - **selectAllStudentsQuery**, then I created an operation - **selectAllStudentsOp** and a REST resource - **students** (to GET ALL students).

Then when I tried with these http requests:

```
http://DSS_SERVER/DSS_NAME/selectAllStudentsOp
http://DSS_SERVER/DSS_NAME/students
```

It response the same result to me is list of students.

So what is the different between operation and a REST resource method in this scenario?

Is it true that if I plan to expose all data services as REST resource and invoke to it by REST style, then I can skip all the operations?

Thanks so much,

Regards,
Trong

Answer (score 2):

The data service can be exposed as SOAP or REST. If you want to expose it as SOAP services you have to use [operations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Defining+Service+Operations) and when you add resource then the query will be exposed as [REST style resource](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS321/Exposing+Data+as+REST+Resources). Yes you can skip to add operations and expose all data services as REST resources. It depends on the usecase and the requirement.

Thanks

Chanika